# Changing Eclipse panes in perspective

Tags: eclipse

The debug perspective in Eclipse shows three horizontal panes on top of eachother. I would like to change them to vertical panes, like in development mode. How can I change that?

[image: Eclipse debug perspective]

Answer (score -1):

Drag and drop, that's all you need!

Hope it helped.